# Unable to figure out how I can write the results back to the same worksheet when I go for concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl, concurrent.futures

I've used `openpyxl` library to read different ticker names from a worksheet and then use those tickers in a [website](https://www.otcmarkets.com/) to produce results and finally write the results  back to the same worksheet right next to the tickers in their concerning cells.

When I run the script without implementing multiprocessing within it, I find it working flawlessly.

However, I can't figure out as to how I can write the results back to the worksheet in their concerning cells when I go for this library `concurrent.futures`.

My current attempt:

```
import requests
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import concurrent.futures as futures

wb = load_workbook('Screener.xlsx')
ws = wb['Screener-1']

link = 'https://backend.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/company/profile/full/{}?'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
}
params = {
    'symbol': ''
}

def get_info(ticker):
    target_link = link.format(ticker)
    params['symbol'] = ticker
    r = requests.get(target_link,params,headers=headers)
    try:
        address = r.json()['address']
    except (AttributeError,KeyError,IndexError): 
        address = ""
    try:
        website = r.json()['website']
    except (AttributeError,KeyError,IndexError): 
        website = ""
    return address,website

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ticker_list = []
    for row in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
        if ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value==None:break          
        ticker = ws.cell(row=row,column=1).value
        ticker_list.append(ticker)

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_info, ticker): ticker for ticker in ticker_list}
        for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            address,website = future.result()[0],future.result()[1]
            print(address,website)

    #         ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = '{}'.format(address)
    #         ws.cell(row=row, column=3).value = '{}'.format(website)
    # wb.save('Screener.xlsx')
```

Few tickers for your test:

```
tickers = ['URBT','TPRP','CRBO','PVSP','TSPG','VMHG','MRTI','VTMC','TORM','SORT']
```

> How can I write the results back to the same worksheet while doing reverse search using concurrent.futures?

In case you wish to know where exactly I'm trying to write the data to, this is how ***[the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmzhp.jpg)*** looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using `openpyxl`, I'd recommend using `pandas`, as you might find it a bit easier to work with workbooks. `openpyxl` powers `pandas` `read_excel`.

Assuming you have a file `Screener.xlsx` that has column `Symbol`, like so:

[image]

You can grab the missing data and update the workbook.

Here's how:

```py
import concurrent.futures as futures

import pandas as pd
import requests

link = 'https://backend.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/company/profile/full/{}'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                  '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
}


def get_info(ticker) -> dict:
    r = requests.get(link.format(ticker), headers=headers)
    print(f"Fetching data for {ticker}...")
    try:
        address = r.json()["address1"]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
        address = "None"
    try:
        website = r.json()["website"]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
        website = "None"
    return {"ticker": ticker, "address": address, "website": website}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel("Screener.xlsx")
    tickers = df["Symbol"].to_list()
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        future_to_url = {
            executor.submit(get_info, ticker): ticker for ticker in tickers
        }
    tickers_scraped = [
        future.result() for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
    ]
    sorted_tickers = sorted(
        tickers_scraped, key=lambda i: tickers.index(i["ticker"])
    )
    df.loc[:, ["Address", "Website"]] = [
        [i["address"], i["website"]] for i in sorted_tickers
    ]
    df.to_excel("Screener.xlsx", index=False)
```

To get this:

[image]

EDIT:

Here's a *pure* `pandas` approach *without* sorting the scraped data first.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel("Screener.xlsx")
    tickers = df["Symbol"].to_list()
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        future_to_url = {
            executor.submit(get_info, ticker): ticker for ticker in tickers
        }
    tickers_scraped = [
        future.result() for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
    ]
    df_scraped = pd.DataFrame(tickers_scraped).set_index("ticker")
    df = df.set_index("Symbol")
    df[["Address", "Website"]] = df_scraped[["address", "website"]]
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.to_excel("Screener.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Overwriting anything or creating a new sheet will make everything messy as there are other records in column D to H which all are connected to the tickers in column A and which is why I found it difficult to solve. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't include *any* data on the workbook itself, so I couldn't have known that. If you could edit your question with a *sample* of your dataframe, that would make things *a lot* easier. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the post to clarify what i meant. Btw, in your suggested script if `address` line throws any error within try block, `website` line will never be executed even when it will possibly have any value.

Comment: @MITHU you're right. I've added extra `try except` block and updated the answer.

Comment: You are incredible! Although I find it hard to understand stuff when it comes to write data to an excel file using panda, your implementation perfectly did the trick. If I'm not wrong, this line `tickers_scraped =` is outside `with` block, right? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the good words. `pandas` is a challenging but an amazing library, I highly recommend exploring some of it's basic concepts. And yes, I intentionally put everything else outside of the `with open` block. The results of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` are still within the global scope, so everything works.